# Why is grep missing missing matches when searching multiple directories?

Tags: bash, cygwin, grep

Trying to grep the files in several child directories, grep returns nothing.

```
~/box/raw $ grep ":2259\"" f*/hh*.adt
~/box/raw $
```

But when I descend into one of the child directories, grep finds a match.

```
~/box/raw/f040 $ grep ":2259\"" hh*.adt
hh_sr2014_v8.adt:"2/23/2015 2:33:49 PM","Leave Field:Introduction.BQ1a","Cause:Next Field","Status:Normal","Value:2259"
```

This works (i.e., finds the match):

```
~/box/raw $ grep ":2259\"" f040/hh*.adt
```

But these don't:

```
~/box/raw $ grep ":2259\"" f???/hh*.adt
~/box/raw $ grep ":2259\"" f???/hh_sr2014_v8.adt
~/box/raw $ grep ":2259\"" f*/hh_sr2014_v8.adt
```

There seem to be some rules about wildcard expansion in directory names that I don't understand. What are they?

This is on Cygwin on a Windows 7 machine. `uname -r` gives me "1.7.33-2(0.280/5/3)".

Comment: can you try some testing with other commands e.g. `ls`, I think this may show that the issue is down to cygwin's shell expansion not `grep`.

Comment: +1 gogoud, `~/box $ ls r*/f*` gives "no such file or directory", because `ls` and `grep` are case sensitive but the filesystem isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
shopt -s nocaseglob
```

Then log out and back in to Cygwin (not Windows), now the bash shell will not be case sensitive any more when it is globbing filenames. More info [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html).